# find expired domains with StormCrawler

Tags: stormcrawler

We need to find the list of expired domains by using StormCrawler. We get http_response_status code 200 for expired domains. By in our project, we want to find these expired domains. How can I do that in StormCrawler project?

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to detect expired domains being [parked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_parking) or [warehoused](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_warehousing), you need a different approach than to rely whether the domain name is resolved by DNS and the domain homepage is fetched with HTTP status "200 OK":

- analyze the content which usually includes a hint that this domain is parked or for sale
- the DNS records / IP addresses of many parked domains usually point to the same "parking" server

Note that even if fetching of a domain homepage fails to fetch the domain is not necessarily expired - it might be in use not for www but for other services (email, etc.)